# ServiceNow Integration with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, servicenow

I am tasked with Integrating Servicenow with Docusign for sending Mutual NDA for digital signature.  This is to be achieved through a request item.

Does anyone know how to do that.  I have tried ServiceNow Community and it has a cryptic answers.  I am new to restful integrations and have no clue on how to do this.

Can someone suggest

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more? like what is the desirable process flow? from where the request would be generated? etc etc...help us to help you...

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-built app called eSignifi in the ServiceNow store that you can use.

https://store.servicenow.com/sn_appstore_store.do#!/store/application/b7198016db612200ec1672ffbf96199a